# Is there a Kauffman bracket invariant of colored links?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, knot-link

I want to distinguish between links where the components have different (or same) colors.
In the Alexander polynomial we can assign a different variable to each component, but what about a Kauffman bracket? Is there a generalization so that we could distinguish between multi-component links where some of the components are colored?

Answer (score 1):

The Jones polynomial can be understood as coming from representations of quantum groups. The regular Jones polynomial comes from the defining representation of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$. It is possible to color/label components of the link with different representations of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ to obtain various colored Jones polynomials.

However, this is a little different than the multivariable Alexander polynomial because the invariant you end up with is still a polynomial in a single variable.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any (readable) references for 1) The Jones obtained from the representation of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ and 2) The coloring/labeling of components?

Comment: I have heard great things about "An Introduction to Quantum and Vassiliev Knot Invariants" by Jackson and Moffatt and at a glance it looks nice. I think Chapter 9 would have the details you are asking about

Comment: I should also say, because of how "nice" representations of $U_q(\mathcal{sl}_2)$ are, there are deep relations between the colored Jones polynomial and Jones polynomials of cables. Sometimes the cabling construction is used as a definition of the colored Jones polynomial to make working with it easier